# Anime where a guy tutors a girl in magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

Basically this guy comes to tutor this girl in magic. I think she's royalty and she isn't good at it.

In the first episode or two there is a school battle (I think) with royalty but they maybe use weapons but she again isn't that good. I remember at the end when they're hunting this person down, the teacher ends up being a vampire or werewolf.

The teacher has black hair and looks kinda preppy and I think he had a suitcase and gloves.

Comment: Was this a fantasy setting? Contemporary? Futuristic? Was the girl human? Elven? Royalty herself? Did you see more than one episode? Do you remember any other plotlines? And were they hunting down the teacher? Why were they hunting him?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this might be *[Assassin's Pride](https://assassinspride.fandom.com/wiki/Anime)*.

[image: Front cover of Assassin's Pride]

> In a world where only nobles wield the sacred power of mana to wage war against the creatures of darkness, a curious absence of ability places young Melida in a precarious position. Under the guise of tutelage, Kufa, a ruthless assassin, is sent to assess Melida’s abilities and determine if she is the true-born heir of the prestigious Angel family. If she does not measure up to her family’s expectations, another, more ruthless plan will be set in motion…

Kufa is half-vampire.

> Kufa Vampir is the main protagonist of the series *Assassin's Pride*. He is half human and half vampire, the strongest of the Lancanthrope class. He also belongs to the Guild Jack Raven.

### Trailer

A search for `anime magic tutor vampire` brought me to [this page](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/tutors), and *Assassin's Pride* looked the most likely, so I searched for more details, which brought me to the wiki.